# broken upgrade from 10.04 to 12.04 on a VPS - recoverable?

Tags: 12.04, 10.04, upgrade, apt

I have a VPS hosted 1500 km away. It originally came with 9.10 - and this morning I decided that I really should get to an LTS release, and figured I'd jump to 12.04.

Researching, I discovered that there is no direct path between 9.10 and 12.04, but that I could upgrade via 10.04. After backing up my data, I dove in. The upgrade to 10.04 was successful, and I proceeded to upgrade to 12.04.

Things started to go wrong.

First, I got an error with GLIBC - I retried and got the same error. That's when I stopped the upgrade. I then tried another round of `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` and got a list of "unmet dependencies":

```
  apt: Depends: ubuntu-keyring but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15) but 2.11.1-0ubuntu7.11 is to be installed
       Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.6) but 4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1 is to be installed
       PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.15.7.2) but 1.15.5.6ubuntu4.6 is to be installed
  apt-utils: Depends: libapt-pkg-libc6.10-6-4.8
  libapt-inst1.4: Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14) but 2.11.1-0ubuntu7.11 is to be installed
  libapt-pkg4.12: Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15) but 2.11.1-0ubuntu7.11 is to be installed
                  Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.6) but 4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1 is to be installed
  libc6: Depends: libc-bin (= 2.11.1-0ubuntu7.11) but 2.15-0ubuntu10.2 is to be installed
  libept0: Depends: libapt-pkg-libc6.10-6-4.8
  libnih-dbus1: Depends: libnih1 (= 1.0.3-4ubuntu9) but 1.0.1-1 is to be installed
```

I tried to see if I could do something about these - using `apt-get -f install`. This told me that I would need to upgrade my kernel. I found instructions on how to do this, but when I ran apt-get to install the new linux headers, I got the same dependency errors.

I found another answer here where someone else had had an interruption in their upgrade - and tried the solution that worked for them: `sudo apt-get -f dist-upgrade`

This resulted in the error:

```
E: Could not perform immediate configuration on 'python2.7-minimal'.Please see man 5 apt.conf under APT::Immediate-Configure for details. (2)
```

I tried to resolve this by:

```
apt-get install -o APT::Immediate-Configure=false -f apt python-minimal
```

But this simply ended up with this last list of dependency errors:

```
apt: Depends: ubuntu-keyring but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15) but 2.11.1-0ubuntu7.11 is to be installed
       Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.6) but 4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1 is to be installed
       PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.15.7.2) but 1.15.5.6ubuntu4.6 is to be installed
  apt-utils: Depends: libapt-pkg-libc6.10-6-4.8
  libapt-inst1.4: Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14) but 2.11.1-0ubuntu7.11 is to be installed
  libapt-pkg4.12: Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15) but 2.11.1-0ubuntu7.11 is to be installed
                  Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.6) but 4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1 is to be installed
  libc6: Depends: libc-bin (= 2.11.1-0ubuntu7.11) but 2.15-0ubuntu10.2 is to be installed
  libept0: Depends: libapt-pkg-libc6.10-6-4.8
  libnih-dbus1: Depends: libnih1 (= 1.0.3-4ubuntu9) but 1.0.1-1 is to be installed
  python: Depends: python-minimal (= 2.6.5-0ubuntu1) but 2.7.3-0ubuntu2 is to be installed
  python-apt: Depends: libapt-pkg-libc6.10-6-4.8
  python-minimal: Depends: python2.7-minimal (>= 2.7.3) but it is not going to be installed
                  Breaks: python-support (< 1.0.10ubuntu2) but 1.0.4ubuntu1 is to be installed
  synaptic: Depends: libapt-pkg-libc6.10-6-4.8
```

Any ideas on how to dig out of this hole?

Comment: As it turns out, I didn't quite read the small print on the VPS. This one uses a shared kernel - so upgrading wouldn't work since the kernel couldn't keep up, hence the dependency problems. Luckily, it is a quick and easy thing to restore to the original installation and I have backups.

Comment: I am not clear it uses a shared kernel does that mean other users are also using the same kernel? Or there are other sys admins on your server

Comment: It's a VPS on shared hardware... the way that the VPS is setup is such that the kernel is shared across all VPS on that hardware host - not very compartmentalised, really

Comment: Is there any software available in Ubuntu which can make my laptop or a small spare computer I have work as a VPS

Comment: Short answer: no, not really in Ubuntu. Middle answer: there are various virtualisation systems available, with different strengths and weaknesses. Long answer: http://serverfault.com/questions/ask

Answer (score 0):

I also had the python-problem and then lots of unmet dependencies. At last, after finding out that the real problem is in `apt`, I just did:

```
cd /var/cache/apt/archives
dpkg -i apt_0.8.16~exp12ubuntu10.16_amd64.deb
```

The following `apt-get -f install` installed all packages, that didn't work before and the following `apt-get dist-upgrade` (nearly) worked like a charm.

But after this mess of an upgrade with the **do-release-upgrade**-script from 10.04 to 12.04 and similar problems on other Ubuntu release upgrades, I took the decision that any new systems definitely won't have Ubuntu any more, but the good, old, stable and reliable Debian, with which I never experienced such problems!

Hope this helps You too !

Best wishes - Ralph from Germany